# How does Network Address Translation affect computers on the network?

Tags: nat

(I’m asking the question here because most of the other similar questions on StackExchange seem to be here — please let me know if there is a more appropriate community).

I have a number of computers on a network with a Linux Server running iptables, which is using Network Address Translation.

Not being an expert, I understand that the role of NAT is to take the internal 198 IP addresses, forward them to the external host under a common external IP address, and, when the response arrives, reverse the process.

If a number of internal machines make requests to the same external host, does this mean that host thinks they’re all coming from the same machine? What implications would that have for security or if the host wants to blacklist a machine?

Comment: Pretty much yes, the host will think they are all coming from the same IP address and if that IP address is blacklisted then all machines on the internal network using the same external IP address will be blocked as well.

Comment: @DanielBarbarian Would that also have any security implications if the host thinks they’re all the same machine?

Comment: @Manngo You might get better answers re security on [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Manngo That depends very much on what your host does. I can't tell exactly how since I don't have the details. Either way, try https://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

"*The router knows where packets belong because The router saves ... an address translation table. It remembers what inside-outside address translations it has made. As such, one inside address equals one outside address, and the out-on-the-internet destination is irrelevant. This, of course, ignores the firewall present in practically every NAT router, which tracks full connections:*"

[How NAT Port forwarding works](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12540/how-nat-portforwarding-tcp-ip-works)